# Passing json from Angular JS to Node JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, express

I am trying to combine my front-end(Angular) and backend(Node) but some how front-end did not pass json to backend

Here is my html code with Angular-js

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>Testing
<script src = "angular.min.js" ></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
   $scope.submit= function(){
      var data = $.param({
        book: JSON.stringify({
            author: $scope.author,
            title : $scope.title,
            body : $scope.body
        })
      });
    console.log(data)
      $http.post("/", data).success(function(data, status) {
        console.log('Data posted successfully');
      })
   }
});
</script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">    
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
      Author:
      <input type="text" ng-model="author">
      <br>
      <br> Title:
      <input type="text" ng-model="title">
      <br>
      <br> Body:
      <input type="author" ng-model="body">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()">
    </form>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

My node Application is look like below.

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.body)   
    res.status(200).send('Ok')
})

console.log('server running at 3000!')
app.listen(3000);
```

I am getting Index.html at my browser at'/' route but when i submit nothing is happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have u analyzed the data being sent? like use chrome dev tools network tab. Or is a request not being sent out in the first place?

Comment: In inspecting page it fails to load "angular.min.js" but I have put it in the same folder I don't know why it happend @GilbertNwaiwu

Comment: Are u saying angular.min.js doesnt load at all?

Comment: Yes. I've used its online version <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js" ></script>

Comment: That was the exact problem. I've tried with "node-modules/angular/angular.min.js" and "angular.min.js" placing file on both location but it was not loading

Comment: "...it was..." so everything working now?

Comment: Not everything. POST request works perfectly but it has not given route and OK was not print on screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128948/discussion-between-gilbert-nwaiwu-and-abhishek-parikh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can u try this

```
var data = {
  book: {            
    author: $scope.author,
    title : $scope.title,
    body : $scope.body
  }
}

$http.post("/", data).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log('Data posted successfully');
})
```

Comment: Problem I am facing is with res.status(200).send('Ok').
It is not sending OK @sunil

Comment: please help me to re route it